# Git: push into brach such that deleted files are restored

Tags: git

Suppose I have a master branch consisting of finished and unfinished content.

```
master/
  foo # finished
  bar # unfinished
```

And I would like to create a release branch from the master branch:

```
git branch -b release
```

Where I can strip out all of the unifinished content and leave just the finished material that is ready for release:

```
git remove bar
vi foo # perhaps make changes
```

And somehow be in a position where I can update `master` with changes to `foo` in release without deleting the files in `master` that I have deleted in `release`, and update `release` with changes to files that I have perhaps deleted in `release`, but which are now finished in `master`...

Is this kind of `merge/pull/push` relationship possible with `git`? Perhaps with some deeper `git` knowledge and option flags?

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout a new branch add the finished content, stash the unfinished, and add the unfinished to a new branch.

```
git checkout -b release
git add FINISHED_FILES
git commit -m "My update"
git stash
git checkout -b dev origin/master
git stash pop
git add UNFINISHED_FILES
git commit -m "I am working"
```